# SHAREPOINT - Javascript to chance the choice column values

Tags: javascript, choice-field

How can I change the values on choice column using Javascript?
for example: If I select USA on another column, the choice column options will be NY,MIAMI and TEXAS. but, if I select Brazil, the options will be Rio de Janeiro, Sao Paulo and Bahia.

thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible , by Cascade Dropdown List using **SPServices** , and **SPCascadeDropdowns** function, take a look on the sample in the below link

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/37676.sharepoint-2013-cascade-dropdown-list-using-spservices-spservices-spcascadedropdowns.aspx